# Assign ID to current table row dynamically, tr using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I need to assign id to specific row in table out of 5 using jQuery function.

I have managed to managed to apply CSS for test purpose but it applying all rows not only the current one

```
 $("#AdditionalTenent").find("tr").css("background-color", "red");
```

### Table structure

```
<table class="table-bordered">
     <thead>
       <tr id="AdditionalTenentHeader">
                                <th>Student UWL ID</th>
                                <th>Title</th>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Middle Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                            <tr class="AdditionalTenentRecord">
                                <td><input type="text" value="" name="listedStudentUWLID" id="listedStudentUWLID" class="form-control additionalTententUWLID"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" value="" name="listedStudentTitle" id="listedStudentTitle" class="form-control listedStudentTitle"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" value="" name="listedStudentFirstName" id="listedStudentFirstName" class="form-control listedStudentFirstName"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" value="" name="listedStudentMiddleName" id="listedStudentMiddleName" class="form-control listedStudentMiddleName"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" value="" name="listedStudentLastName" id="listedStudentLastName" class="form-control listedStudentLastName"></td>
                                <td><a class="DeleteEntryInline_Icon DeleteAdditionalTenentEntry" href="#"></a></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="AdditionalTenentRecord">
                                <td><input type="text" value="" name="listedStudentUWLID" id="listedStudentUWLID" class="form-control additionalTententUWLID"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" value="" name="listedStudentTitle" id="listedStudentTitle" class="form-control listedStudentTitle"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" value="" name="listedStudentFirstName" id="listedStudentFirstName" class="form-control listedStudentFirstName"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" value="" name="listedStudentMiddleName" id="listedStudentMiddleName" class="form-control listedStudentMiddleName"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" value="" name="listedStudentLastName" id="listedStudentLastName" class="form-control listedStudentLastName"></td>
                                <td><a class="DeleteEntryInline_Icon DeleteAdditionalTenentEntry" href="#"></a></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="AdditionalTenentRecord">
                                <td><input type="text" value="" name="listedStudentUWLID" id="listedStudentUWLID" class="form-control additionalTententUWLID"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" value="" name="listedStudentTitle" id="listedStudentTitle" class="form-control listedStudentTitle"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" value="" name="listedStudentFirstName" id="listedStudentFirstName" class="form-control listedStudentFirstName"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" value="" name="listedStudentMiddleName" id="listedStudentMiddleName" class="form-control listedStudentMiddleName"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" value="" name="listedStudentLastName" id="listedStudentLastName" class="form-control listedStudentLastName"></td>
                                <td><a class="DeleteEntryInline_Icon DeleteAdditionalTenentEntry" href="#"></a></td>
                            </tr>

         </tbody>
  </table>
```

I have tried following jQuery script but its still applying css to all records in table not the $(this) one!

```
   $("#AdditionalTenent").find(".AdditionalTenentRecord").closest("tr").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

### javaScript Code

```
 $(".additionalTententUWLID").on("change", function () {

    var StudentUWLID = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetStudentRecordByID", "StudentProfile")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { _GivenStudentUWLID: StudentUWLID },
            cache: false
        }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            if (data.RecordStatus == "NotAvailable")
            {
                $(this).MyMessageDialog({
                    _messageBlockID: "_StatusMessage",
                    _messageContent: "<div class='warningMessage'> <h4>Given Student Cannot Be Enter As Additional Tenant.</h4> <br/> Student Need to Have their Profile Completed On Student Village Portal Before Can Be Added As Additional Tenant Within The Tendency Form! <br/><br/> Or Enter Correct Student UWL ID "+"</div>",
                    _messageBlockWidth: "400px"
                });
            }
            else if(data.RecordStatus=="recordFound")
            {
                alert(data.Response);

                var paraedData = JSON.parse(data.Response);

               // alert(paraedData.Title + "   " + paraedData.FirstName);

                //  $("#AdditionalTenent").find("tr").css("background-color", "red");

                $("#AdditionalTenent").find(".AdditionalTenentRecord").closest("tr").css("background-color", "yellow");
              ???????????????????
               //I need to apply css or ID to row only in use so that in following line I can set values to text field only in single row NOT all of them 
         $("#AdditionalTenent").find(".listedStudentTitle").val(paraedData.Title);
                $("#AdditionalTenent").find(".listedStudentFirstName").val(paraedData.FirstName);
                $("#AdditionalTenent").find(".listedStudentMiddleName").val(paraedData.MiddleName);
                $("#AdditionalTenent").find(".listedStudentLastName").val(paraedData.LastName);

            }

        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

          alert("error");
        });

    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "current one"? You could use `nth-child` or something like that for choosing only one out of few elements (http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Comment: the one in use ... $(this)

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').attr('id','someId')` perhaps?

Comment: @toxic: can you paste all your JavaScript / jQuery code please?

Comment: i have updated my question above

Comment: @toxic: wouldn't `$(this).parent().css('background-color', 'red')` help here? your `tr` is the parent of your current `$(this)` object if I am not wrong.

Comment: its not working.... I am getting no response from $(this) at all ... I dont know why

Comment: is it because I have input type textbox inside td????

Comment: store a reference to your current `$('.additionalTententUWLID')` object in a variable called `self` for example before the `$.ajax(...)` call, and then inside this `$.ajax(...)` call, use `self` instead of `$(this)` from the jQuery statement I mentioned above.

Comment: The app is taking additionalTententUWLID at run time, take this id to back-end coding and based on ID .. get student record which I need to populate in that row....

Comment: many thanks Tahir... with you help I have found answer...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a jQuery click event, if that is the case, you can use:

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

Comment: I add the class to each tr and then try following line but is still applying css to all rows in table     $("#AdditionalTenent").find(".AdditionalTenentRecord").closest("tr").css("background-color", "yellow");

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".additionalTententUWLID").on("change", function () {

    var StudentUWLID = $(this).val();

    $(this).attr('id', StudentUWLID);

    $.ajax({............my rest of code
```

and in success response

```
 $("#" + StudentUWLID).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');

 $("#" + StudentUWLID).closest('tr').find(".listedStudentTitle").val(paraedData.Title);
  $("#" + StudentUWLID).closest('tr').find(".listedStudentFirstName").val(paraedData.FirstName);
  $("#" + StudentUWLID).closest('tr').find(".listedStudentMiddleName").val(paraedData.MiddleName);
  $("#" + StudentUWLID).closest('tr').find(".listedStudentLastName").val(paraedData.LastName);
```